# Number of records reducing after mongo mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

This is my mapreduce code:

```js
DBCollection mongoCollection = MongoDAO.getCollection();
String map = "function() {"
        + "for (index in this.positions.positionList) {"
        + "emit(this._id+'|'+this.headline+'|'+"
        + "this.location.name+'|'+this.location.country.code+'|'+this.publicProfileUrl+'|'+"
        + "this.positions.positionList[index].title+'|'+"
        + "this.positions.positionList[index].company.name+'|'+this.positions.positionList[index].company.industry+'|'+"
        + "this.positions.positionList[index].company.type+'|'+this.positions.positionList[index].company.size+'|'+"
        + "this.lastName+'|'+this.firstName+'|'+this.industry+'|'+this.updatedDate+'|' , {count: 1});"
        + "}}";
String reduce = "";
MapReduceCommand mapReduceCommand = new MapReduceCommand(
        mongoCollection, map, reduce.toString(), "final_result",
        MapReduceCommand.OutputType.REPLACE, null);

MapReduceOutput out = mongoCollection.mapReduce(mapReduceCommand);
```

Currently I'm working with 140,000 records. But while doing mapreduce number of records reduces to 90,000. There are no duplicate records in the dataset.

Comment: Please use normal numbers. Most people don't know how big lakh is :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a map reduce without a reduce?

Comment: My requirement is bit complex,i need to upload data from mongo to hive.So I am saving it to a collection and writing to a file.Even if i try with 30 records , the output will be 25 records.

Comment: Apparently, `14 lakh` == `1,400,000` : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: is there a question in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your emit to emit the _id as the key and the pipe-delimited string as a value. As an example:

```
emit(this._id, [this._id, this.a, this.b,...].join('|'))
```

What I think is happening is that you are making overly long strings in the key. There is a limit of 1KB (in 2.0, up from 800B before) for _id values which is what the key becomes.

Also, rather than rolling your own, you may want to look into the prepackaged mongodb-hadoop connector: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop

Comment: Hi,I tried pipe seperated values as 'value' and 'this.id' as 'key'.But no appreciable change in output..Anyways thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please also add a reduce that just returns values[0] and possibly assert(values.length == 1). If that doesn't help, please update the question to include the output with the verbose flag set. This may be easier to test using the mongo shell than a java app.